# With flask can you play a video saved in a databse?

Tags: python, flask

I saved a file in a database and would like to play it in a browser. The data of the video file is saved in a LargeBinary column. Here is the part where  I'm trying to ply the video after retrieving it:

```
@app.route('/play/')
def friends():
    file_data = Videos.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    a = send_file(file_data.data, attachment_filename='video.mkv')

    return render_template('seprate_ep.html', video=a)
```

And in the HTML file, I just referenced the video how you normaly would like this:

```
<video src="{{ video }}"></video>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You should create two urls, one for the template, and one that streams the video content to the user.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem –– but I can't get the video itself to play as they are saved as binary in a database.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue and devised the following solution. After conducting extensive research, I was unable to identify a direct method of transmitting binary data directly to HTML. Therefore, I opted for a straightforward approach by storing the video locally and subsequently passing the file path to the template.

In Python, using the Flask web framework, you can implement this solution as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Assume Videos schema has file path in them
    file_data = Videos.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    video_path = file_data.path
    
    return render_template('index.html', video_path=video_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```